# Flutter ReorderableListView doesn't work with TextFields

Tags: flutter

The widgets in my [ReorderableListView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html) are essentially [TextField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField-class.html)s. When long pressing on a widget, after the time when the long press should cause the widget to "hover," instead the TextField receives focus. How can I make the drag & drop effect take precedence over the TextField? I would still like a normal tap to activate the TextField.

The code below demonstrates my issue.

I also tried to use this unofficial [flutter_reorderable_list](https://github.com/knopp/flutter_reorderable_list) package. (To test this one, replace the Text widget on [this line](https://github.com/knopp/flutter_reorderable_list/blob/808e9268935d66e83e55512d28488bb11899e610/example/lib/main.dart#L218) of the example code with a TextField.)

I'm willing to use any ugly hacks to get this working, including modifying the Flutter source code!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final children = List<Widget>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      children.add(Container(
        color: Colors.pink, // Only the pink area activates drag & drop
        key: Key("$i"),
        height: 50.0,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ReorderableListView(
            children: children,
            onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) => null,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do multiple things in there to fix this.

1. First disable the default handler in **ReorderableListView** by setting `buildDefaultDragHandles: false` in its properties.
2. Wrap you child widget inside `ReorderableDragStartListener` widget like this

```
ReorderableDragStartListener(
   index: i,
   child: Container(
       color: Colors.grey,
       margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
       child: TextFormField(initialValue: "Child $i", ),
   ),
 ),
```

3. Then inside this `ReorderableDragStartListener` wrap your child in `InkWell` and `AbsorbPointer`. Then use `FocusNode` to focus inner TextField on single tap.
   Like this

```
InkWell(
   onTap: () => _focusNode.requestFocus(),
   onLongPress: () {
                  print("long pressed");
   },
   child: AbsorbPointer(
      child: TextFormField(initialValue: "Child $i", focusNode: _focusNode,),
   ),
),
```

4. You need to create multiple FocusNode for all the items in list. You can do this by using List or by simpling creating a new FocusNode inside the loop.

Complete code example here https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1